# How to use variable inside css3 calc function with less?

Tags: css, less

I am using the math option `parens-division`. Please do not suggest using strict/legacy to resolve this issue.

What I ultimately want is this: `calc(100% - 13.75rem)`

However, I want to use variables in my defintion. With parens-division I had

```
@subtract: (220/16rem); // hack to work-around nested math interpretations
.zzz {
    width: calc(~"100% -" @subtract);
}
```

After updating some of my builds I started getting errors on `(220/16rem)` so now I have tried

```
@subtract: (220/16); // hack to work-around nested math interpretations
.zzz {
    width: calc(~"100% - @{subtract}rem");
}
```

but with no success. Help appreciated

Comment: you cannot divide by a unit in calc

Comment: on http://lesscssismore.com/ljshn6/ it seems working fine

Comment: Have you tried `(220rem / 16)`, putting the unit on the numerator instead of denominator?

Answer (score 1):

I've created a pen to test a combination of your solutions.

Seems to be working:

```
@subtract: (220/16rem); // hack to work-around nested math interpretations
.zzz {
    background: red;
    height: 50px;
    width: calc(~"100% - @{subtract}");
}
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/dgZWVe